# Input values are not submitted on a second submission on my Livewire form

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-livewire-wiremodel

On my Livewire form I have a few text inputs which uses wire:model.defer

```
<input type="text" wire:model.defer="otp1" >
<input type="text" wire:model.defer="otp2" >

<button class="btn btn-primary" wire:click="verifyOTP">
    Verify
</button>
```

When I click a button to submit this form on the first time, the form is submitted properly. I can get the values in otp1 and otp2.

But, if I click the same button to submit this form again on a second or third time, the values for otp1 and otp2 will be empty, although I can still see the values for the two text inputs on the page.

Below is my component code:

```
class OTPForm extends Component
{
    public $otp1;
    public $otp2;

    public function verifyOTP() {
        $otp_attempt = $this->otp1 . $this->otp2;
        dd($otp_attempt);
    }
}
```

I cannot just use wire:model nor wire:model.lazy

Although I can see the values on the page, in the text inputs, the values are not present in $this->otp1 and $this->otp2 on subsequent submissions.

However, if I re-enter (re-type) the values in the text inputs, then they will be submitted and present in $this->otp1 and $this->otp2.

How can I fix this problem, or if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: remove the `dd`. By using `dd` you're stopping Livewire from completing its full cycle and thus won't be able to send the data back to the frontend. It's basically unable to properly hydrate the properties.